# How to update gerrit repos with changes submitted directly to git?

Tags: git, repository, synchronization, gerrit

I am currently dealing with a situation where some people are test driving gerrit for code review, but those not yet using it can still push code directly to the remote git repo.

The thing is, gerrit's own repo is of course not updated with all the changes.
How can I get it to be in sync with git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerrit doesn't currently support referencing upstream repositories as the master.  There are several requests for this so users can put Gerrit in front of Github, but it isn't currently supported.  You have a couple options:

1. Switch to Gerrit, but allow bypassing review.  Gerrit is the master and people test driving code review can do so, but users wanting to bypass review can push directly to the repositories.
2. Set up some scripts to sync Gerrit's copy of the repositories with upstream.  This will get tricky if there are merge conflicts, but might be doable.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, a solution proposed by a colleague of mine was to place hooks both on gerrit and on our git in order for them to sync everytime a commit was done.
The thing is: depending on the development flow people follow, it can generate conflicts that never get solved.

Anyway, in the meantime we got to experiment with github enterprise and we liked it so much we are migrating :D

Thank you very much! 

For some reason I didn't get notified on this answer via email, given we changed strategy it took me longer to come back to it, but I still wanted to say thanks and leave some more feedback :)