# Create new Gerrit project from pre existing git repository

Tags: gerrit, repository, mirror

I'd like to introduce Gerrit on the project I'm working on.

At the moment we already have a git repository with some code committed on it.

I've initialized the project as follows:

1. java -jar gerrit-full-2.5.2.war init --batch -d gerrit-codereview
2. cd gerrit-codereview/git
3. git clone --mirror git@172.18.x.x:my-repo.git

Then I took care of creating users and adding permissions.

I can see changes going through and I can review/publish them. Unfortunately thou, the very final "git push" (that should be executed by Gerrit), does not take place.
If I go manually in the  "gerrit-codereview/git/my-repo.git" folder and I execute "git push" everything works fine.

Any idea?

Comment: a workaround is to use the replication plugin [link](https://review.typo3.org/plugins/replication/Documentation/config.html) (Note the the replication.jar is in the war under WEB-INF/plugins.

Comment: early enter. is it possible that the one above is the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gerrit doesn't currently support referencing external repositories as the master.  You can use the replication plugin (which ships with Gerrit) to push to external repositories, but it won't handle merge conflicts if changes are made upstream.  This is a commonly requested feature.  More information is available at [How to update gerrit repos with changes submitted directly to git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384799/how-to-update-gerrit-repos-with-changes-submitted-directly-to-git/15393748#15393748)

Comment: Hi, thanks brad. After Gerrit will be in place nobody will be allowed to push stuff directly to the _upstream_ git, so hopefully we should be able to avoid conflicts.
Is it fair to say that, even if I initialized Gerrit _master_ repo as a mirror of the _upstream_ one, the only one way at the moment to push change sets to it is via the _replication plugin_?

Comment: Hi Giovanni, correct the only way for Gerrit to push changes is with the replication plugin (or with other custom scripts).  If you don't need to worry about conflicts, this is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for myself is to:

1. Create project on gerrit with same name as original
2. git clone --mirror "project you want to clone"
3. mv "project you cloned".git "your Gerrit installation"/git/

Here is an example. I want to clone raspberry linux kernel and locate it as rpi/linux project on Gerrit

1. Create gerrit project rpi/linux
2. rm -r "your Gerrit installation"/git/rpi/linux.git
3. git clone --mirror git@github.com:raspberrypi/linux.git
4. mv linux.git "your Gerrit installation"/git/rpi/

Comment: This seems to work, and I can clone the repo on my local machine correctly (from gerrit, with all the branches in-tact from the old/origin repo). However, pushing results in:


`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/develop`
`fatal: One or more refs/for/ names blocks change upload`
`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

`Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`